# Adding internal Search function to Screnegraph Brightscript Channell

Tags: search, roku, brightscript

I need to add search functionality to my Brightscript scenegraph script for a Roku Channel. Does anyone have a simple Search sample, or a script I can use to add to a "sliding panel" Roku channel script?

RoSearch has been depreciated.

The current page is very similar to the Sliding Panel example.

Need working Search feature on my Roku Channel.

```
<component name = "minikeyboardexample" extends = "Group" initialFocus = "exampleMiniKeyboard" >

<script type="text/brightscript" >
<![CDATA[
sub init()
  m.testlabel = m.top.FindNode("testLabel")
  m.testpostergrid = m.top.FindNode("testPosterGrid")
  m.testpostergridcontent = createObject("roSGNode","ContentNode")
  m.readPosterGridTask = createObject("roSGNode","postergridCR")
  m.readPosterGridTask.setField("postergriduri","http://test-xml.xml")
  m.readPosterGridTask.observeField("gotitem","buildpostergrid")
  m.readPosterGridTask.observeField("gotcontent","showpostergrid")
  m.readPosterGridTask.control = "RUN"
  m.top.setFocus(true)
end sub

sub buildpostergrid()
  gridposter = createObject("roSGNode","ContentNode")
  gridposter.hdgridposterurl = m.readPosterGridTask.hdgridposterurl
  gridposter.hdposterurl = m.readPosterGridTask.hdposterurl
  gridposter.sdgridposterurl = m.readPosterGridTask.sdgridposterurl
  gridposter.sdposterurl = m.readPosterGridTask.sdposterurl
  gridposter.shortdescriptionline1 = m.readPosterGridTask.shortdescriptionline1
  gridposter.shortdescriptionline2 = m.readPosterGridTask.shortdescriptionline2
  gridposter.x = m.readPosterGridTask.xposterpos
  gridposter.y = m.readPosterGridTask.yposterpos
  gridposter.w = m.readPosterGridTask.wnumcols
  gridposter.h = m.readPosterGridTask.hnumrows
  m.testpostergridcontent.appendChild(gridposter)
end sub

sub showpostergrid()
  m.testlabel.text = "Here's the PosterGrid: "
  m.testpostergrid.content=m.testpostergridcontent
  m.testpostergrid.visible=true
  m.testpostergrid.setFocus(true)
end sub
]]>
</script>



  <children>

    <MiniKeyboard id = "exampleMiniKeyboard" />

    <Label id="testLabel" translation="[100,32]" text="Building PosterGrid... " />

    <PosterGrid
    id="testPosterGrid"
    translation="[100,100]"
    basePosterSize="[240,240]"
    itemSpacing="[32,32]"
    caption1NumLines="1"
    caption2NumLines="1"
    numColumns="4"
    numRows="3"
    />


  </children>

</component>
```

Answer (score 0):

first read following thinds : 
https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/developer-program/discovery/search/implementing-search.md

these code for a search functionality. it applies static way.

```
sub Main()


''Search Screen UI

'REM ******************************************************
'REM Main routine - example of search screen usage
'REM ******************************************************
    print "start"

    'toggle the search suggestions vs. search history behavior
    'this allow you to generate both versions of the example below

    displayHistory = false
    history = CreateObject("roArray", 1, true)

    'prepopulate the search history with sample results

    history.Push("seinfeld")
    history.Push("fraiser")
    history.Push("cheers")
    port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
    screen = CreateObject("roSearchScreen")

    'commenting out SetBreadcrumbText() hides breadcrumb on screen

    screen.SetBreadcrumbText("", "Search Channel")
    screen.SetMessagePort(port)
    if displayHistory
       screen.SetSearchTermHeaderText("Recent Searches:")
        screen.SetSearchButtonText("search") 
        screen.SetClearButtonText("clear history")
        screen.SetClearButtonEnabled(true) 'defaults to true
        screen.SetSearchTerms(history)
    else
        screen.SetSearchTermHeaderText("Suggestions:")
        screen.SetSearchButtonText("search")
        screen.SetClearButtonEnabled(false)
    endif

    print "Doing show screen..."

    screen.Show()

    print "Waiting for a message from the screen..."

    ' search screen main event loop

    done = false
    while done = false
        msg = wait(0, screen.GetMessagePort())
        if type(msg) = "roSearchScreenEvent"
            if msg.isScreenClosed()
                print "screen closed"
                done = true
            else if msg.isCleared()
                print "search terms cleared"
                history.Clear()
            else if msg.isPartialResult()
                print "partial search: "; msg.GetMessage()
                if not displayHistory                    
                     screen.SetSearchTerms(GenerateSearchSuggestions(msg.GetMessage()))
                endif
            else if msg.isFullResult()
                print "full search: "; msg.GetMessage()
                history.Push(msg.GetMessage())
                if displayHistory
                    screen.AddSearchTerm(msg.GetMessage())
                end if

               'uncomment to exit the screen after a full search result:
                'done = true

            else
                print "Unknown event: "; msg.GetType(); " msg: "; sg.GetMessage()
            endif
        endif
    endwhile

    print "Exiting..."
End Sub 

Function GenerateSearchSuggestions(partSearchText As String) As Object
    availableContent = [
        "ch1"
        "ch2"
        "ch3"
        "ch4"
        "ch5"
        "ch6"
        "ch7"
        "ch8"
        ]
    suggestions = []
    if partSearchText <> ""
        partSearchText = LCase(partSearchText)
        for each available in availableContent
            if available.Instr(partSearchText) >= 0
                suggestions.Push(available)
            end if
        end for
    end if
    return suggestions
End Function
End sub
```

this code writes in main.brs file

I hope this code is helpful.

Comment: Roku [Document](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/components/rosearchscreen.md) says "This component is deprecated and will be removed from Roku OS on January 1st, 2019. Beginning July 1st, 2017, any new channels using this component will be rejected during certification. Beginning January 1st, 2018, any updates to existing channels using this component will be rejected during certification."

Comment: Thank you dhir Pratap for the information. You suggest any other way to Search in Roku in Dynamically like Netflix and youtube channel for Roku.

Comment: Yeah as I mentioned in the OP RoSearch has been depreciated.

Comment: here the link roSearchScreen is here https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/brightscript/components/rosearchscreen.md and roSearchScreenEvent is here https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/brightscript/events/rosearchscreenevent.md

Answer (score 0):

Most of the search screens in SceenGraph use a combination of [MiniKeyboard](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/scenegraph/widget-nodes/minikeyboard.md) with a combination of any type of list or grid, such are [MarkupGrid](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/scenegraph/list-and-grid-nodes/markupgrid.md). You add these component to your panels or a group component and manage the transition yourself.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  Easier said that done.  I've tried.  Just can't get a around it.

Comment: True that. Pls let me know the specific issue you are finding and will try to answer that.

Comment: I updated my original question to give you more specifics.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I saw the updated code, the only thing missing is key handler function. See this document for [onKeyEvent](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/scenegraph/component-functions/onkeyevent.md)